# byte[] to bufferedImage conversion gives null

Tags: java, image, awt, javax.imageio

I am trying to convert byte[] array to buffered image so than i can resize the image..but problem is conversion always turned into null.here is my code..

```
 ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(user.getUser_image());
 //Here user.getUser_image() returns byte[] returned from server..
 try {
      BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bais);
      System.out.println("============><================"+image);//Here it prints null
      BufferedImage scaledImage = Scalr.resize(image,48);
 }
 .....and so on
```

Comment: 1) Paste a small (in bytes) image that is giving trouble into the question. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Need to include the code on your server that is generating the byte array, and the code that is sending it to the client. Also, the code on the client that is reading the byte array from the server.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the ImageIO class is not able to select an appropriate ImageReader. The purpose of this could be corrupted byte array or unsupported image type. Try to debug it.